# Rewrite <sub>.domain.com/<path> to /subdomains/<sub>/<path>

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, subdomain

I've got stuck with my mod_rewrite (for about 4 hours, yes, I googled, too).
Basically I want to create dynamic subdomains. So I just create a new folder and it automatically has it's own subdomain. Let me give you an example:

```
/ (root)
    /logs
    /configs
    /otherPrivateStuff
    [...]
    /subdomains (This is, where things get interesting)
        /www            (should be: www.domain.com) [domain.com is automatically 301 to www]
        /aproject       (should be: aproject.domain.com)
        /anotherproject (should be: anotherproject.domain.com)
```

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
# Mod Rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# Subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com(:[0-9]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) subdomains/%1/$1/ [NS,L]
```

http://project.domain.com/path/subpath/file.txt --> http://domain.com/subdomains/project/path/subpath/file.txt

---

This works like a charm, but there is a problem: this rule does not apply, if the url looks like this: http://project.domain.com/subdomains/ This beahaves like there's no rewriting at all.

I do not understand this. Can anybody out here help me? :)

Comment: I don't use Apache anymore. I switched to Node.js. You can close this, if you like to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you want to specifically exclude the "subdomains" directory. To do this, you can simply use:

```
# Mod Rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# Subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com(:[0-9]+)? [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomains
RewriteRule ^(.*) subdomains/%1/$1/ [NS,L]
```

I hope that worked correctly for you.

Comment: This does not effect the strange behaviour. Here is the live example: http://pg.janbuschtoens.de/subdomains/